# How to add a [create] partial view inside a details view or any other with parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, partial-views

I am trying to add a partial view [Create view] inside a details view, capturing the ID as parameter, but it always displays a different error.

I have been looking for a solution and the reason why it fails but there is no a good answer or good tutorial to make this possible.

Details view:

```
@model HumanForceMVC1._1.HF_Projects

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Details";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="slim-mainpanel">
<div class="container">
    <div class="slim-pageheader">
        <ol class="breadcrumb slim-breadcrumb">
            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="/Home">Home</a></li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addNewTaskModal">Create new task</a></li>
        </ol>
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="addNewTaskModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        @*@Html.RenderPartial("AddTaskToProject", Model.HF_Tasks, new ViewDataDictionary { { Pid = Model.Id } })*@
                        @Html.Partial("AddTaskToProject", Model.HF_Tasks, new ViewDataDictionary { { "Pid", Model.Id } })
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

My controller:

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddTaskToProject(int Pid, HF_Tasks Item)
    {
        using (var context = new HumanForceDBEntities())
        {
            HF_Tasks myTask = new HF_Tasks();
            myTask = Item;
            myTask.ProjectAssigned = Pid;
            myTask.TaskStatus = 2;
            myTask.TaskDate = DateTime.Now;
            context.HF_Tasks.Add(myTask);
            context.SaveChanges();
            return PartialView();
        }
    }
```

My Partial View:

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
  { @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>HF_Tasks</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TaskName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TaskName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TaskName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TaskDescription, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TaskDescription, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TaskDescription, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PersonAssigned, "PersonAssigned", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("PersonAssigned", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PersonAssigned, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

Please, somebody who can help me with this.

I appreciate in advance.

Comment: "It always displays a different error". What errors? How are we supposed to help you? Please post additional information such as messages, exception stack, etc.

Comment: Also, the type of the model is not present in your partial view code as well as the source code for the type.

Comment: I meant that I have tried many ways to make it work but all of them failed.

Comment: And what does "failed" look like? How do you know you failed? What do you see? Errors? red boxes? Exceptions?

Comment: The model type for the `Details` view is also missing.

Comment: I tried this: @Html.Partial("AddTaskToProject", Model.HF_Tasks, new ViewDataDictionary { { "Pid", Model.Id } }) but it displays this error: 'The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[HumanForceMVC1._1.HF_Tasks]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'HumanForceMVC1._1.HF_Tasks'.'

Comment: The details model is there, and it works perfectly, but I want to display the create partial with a bootstrap modal, basically I am putting the partial in the bootstrap modal body.

Comment: All of them, It does not allow me to render and use the partial view, do you where I can learn advance things about partials views?

Comment: I have modified the details code in the question.

Comment: Great. Thank you. What about the partial view's model?

Comment: Also, can you please post the action method that loads the model and uses the `Details` view?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the @model  ...HF_Tasks in the partial view on the top similar to what you have in the detail view.

Comment: We dont see it in the partial view @RodolfoA.Calvo, what is the error you are getting? I dont see where are you submitting the form to in Html.beginform(). In the controller you are returning a partialView without a model.

Comment: Is it possible to do what I need using partial views?

Comment: Show us the model of HumanForceMVC1._1.HF_Projects @RodolfoA.Calvo yes it is possible to do render a partial view in the detail view and get the model back to the controller.

Comment: I am new at partial views, so I don't know exactly if it is possible to do what I need.